# Why do python lists persist outside function scope while integers don't?

Tags: python, scope

Python works so that I can update a `list` in place every time a function runs:

```py
list_obj = list()
def increase_list_obj(list_obj, n):
    list_obj.append(n)

print(list_obj)
for n in range(3):
    increase_list_obj(list_obj, n)
    print(list_obj)

OUTPUT:

[]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Based on how the `list` persists I would expect that I can also update an `int` in place every time a function runs:

```py
int_obj = 0
def increase_int_obj(int_obj):
    int_obj += 1

print(int_obj)
for n in range(3):
    increase_int_obj(int_obj)
    print(int_obj)

OUTPUT:
0
0
0
0

EXPECTED:
0
1
2
3
```

Why does the `int` update not work the same way as the `list` update?
How are the persistence and scoping rules different for these two objects?

(I am NOT trying to suggest that the two should behave the same, I am curious about why they don't)

To preempt answers about how to update an `int`: I realize you can update the `int` value by just returning it from the function:

```py
int_obj = 0
def increase_int_obj_v2(int_obj):
    int_obj += 1
    return int_obj

print(int_obj)
for n in range(3):
    int_obj = increase_int_obj_v2(int_obj)
    print(int_obj)

OUTPUT:
0
1
2
3
```

Thank you!

Comment: in the case of the list you are modifying the contents of an object that the name refers to, in case of integers you are changing what the name refers to (assigning a different object)

Comment: *All* values live in a single space, independent of any scopes where names that *refer* to those values reside.

Comment: I highly recommend reading this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in Python can be modified from any scope. The thing about integers is they are immutable objects so whenever they are modified they make a new copy of themselves which will only exist within the scope it is created.

Lists on the other hand are like most other Python objects and will be modified in place allowing for changes to be made regardless of the current scope.

Here is an example using a custom object.

```py
class HoldInt:
  def __init__(self, integer):
    self.integer = integer

int_obj = HoldInt(0)

def modify_int():
  int_obj.integer += 1

print(int_obj.integer)
modify_int()
print(int_obj.integer)
```

```
0
1
```

Comment: More precisely, you *can't* modify an `int`, so there's no need to implement `int.__iadd__`. When `x.__iadd__` doesn't exist, `x += y` desugars to `x = x.__add__(y)` instead of `x = x.__iadd__(y)`.

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer because it combines the excellent points about immutable objects and the scope implications made separately by @PersianMan and user2390182. I wish I could add checks to several answers!

Answer (score 1):

To better understand, you need to know some concepts

`int` is immutable and `list` is mutable

List of Mutable and Immutable objects
Objects of built-in type that are mutable are:

- Lists
- Sets
- Dictionaries
- User-Defined Classes

Objects of built-in type that are immutable are:

- Numbers (Integer, Rational, Float, Decimal, Complex & Booleans)
- Strings
- Tuples
- Frozen Sets
- User-Defined Classes (It purely depends upon the user to define the characteristics)

**what does it mean?**

for more info about immutable and mutable read [this](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)

some objects passing to function by reference and some passing by value
([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value))

Comment: Also it is worth to note that immutable types can be hashed by the `hash`-function and used as dict keys for example. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#immutable-sequence-types

Comment: Mutable types can also be hashed, as long as only immutable part of them are used to compute the hash.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I learned a good point from you.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are local if there is an assignment within a function, otherwise they are global:

```
 i += 1
```

is an **assignment** (`i = i + 1`)! Therefore `i` is a local variable within the function.

```
list_obj.append(n)
```

is a **mutation**! Therefore `list_obj` is looked up in the enclosing namespace which is the global one.

Side note: `+=` can be a mutation for mutable types: `list_obj += [n]` would be a mutation as well.

Comment: Note, `+=` is *always* an assignment. It's just a mutation *as well* when operating on mutable types. It's usually not important, but it comes up when you use `+=` inside a function when the left side isn't intended to be a local (it won't read from the global and assign to a local, it just dies with `UnboundLocalError`), or when you use it on a `list` inside an immutable type, e.g. `mylists = ([], []); mylists[0] += [1,2,3]` will explode (the mutation will have occurred, but the attempt to reassign `mylists[0]` will die; only `.extend` works in that case).